# React Table - Show nested object fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Hey so I cannot figure this out for the life of me. SOS.

I have a JSON with nested objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "internalToolName": "HP ALM",
    "statuses": [
      {
        "id": 57,
        "statusType": "Ok",
        "date": "2018-12-17"
      },
      {
         "id": 67,
         "statusType": "Ok",
         "date": "2018-12-23"
      },
      {
         "id": 37,
         "statusType": "Ok",
         "date": "2018-01-06"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "internalToolName": "Artifactory",
    "appType": null,
    "statuses": [
      {
        "id": 1652,
        "statusType": "Ok",
        "date": "2018-12-31"
      },
      {
         "id": 119,
         "statusType": "Ok",
         "date": "2018-12-28"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to populate a react-table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHuJm.png)

I was able to populate the tool name rows using the 'Internal Tools' header and populated the days of the current month. I'm having trouble figuring out the logic to populate the cells with the status on the given date field of the status object. Here is my code:

```html
export default class ToolsIssue2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      month: moment().format('MMMM, YYYY'),
      internalToolData: [{
        internalToolName: '',
        statuses: [{
          date: '',
          statusType: '',
        }]
      }],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.generateData();
  }

  generateData() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/internal_tool')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          internalToolData: response.data
        });
        console.log(this.state.internalToolData);
      }).catch(error => alert(error));
  }

  setStatusSVG(statusType) {
    switch (statusType) {
      case 'Ok': return <img src={ok} className='OK' alt='ok-logo' />
      case 'Warning': return <img src={warning} className='Warning' alt='warning-logo' />
      case 'Unavailable': return <img src={unavailable} className='Unavailable' alt='unavailable-logo' />
    }
  }

  getMonth() {
    return moment().format('MMMM, YYYY');
  }

  getCurrentColumns() {
    var daysInMonth = moment().daysInMonth();
    var monthDaysColumn = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
      monthDaysColumn.push(
        {
          // id: 'statusDate',
          Header: i,
          accessor: 'statuses',
          Cell: (row) => {
            if(moment(`${row.row.statuses.date}`).year() === moment().year() && moment(`${row.row.statuses.date}`).date() === i) {
              this.setStatusSVG(row.row.statuses.statusType);
            }
          },
          resizable: false,
          sortable: false,
          width: 35,
        })
    }
    return monthDaysColumn;
  }

  render() {
    const { internalToolData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={internalToolData}
          columns={[{
            Header: 'Internal Tools',
            columns: [{
              accessor: 'internalToolName',
              width: 150,
              resizable: false,
            }]
          }, {
            Header: this.getMonth(),
            columns: this.getCurrentColumns(),
          }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={15}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with react table however from the looks of the docs, you need to modify the organisation of the data.